# Getting foreign key member "null" in ActiveAndroid

Tags: android, activeandroid

I'm implementing ActiveAndroid in my Android app, for that I'm referring [this link](http://www.activeandroid.com/). My problem definition is, I'm getting data list from server with help of retrofit library. After getting data list I'm inserting data into my "ActiveAndroid" DB. While debugging my app, I checked that, data for foreign key and other data members of model class is correct, but when I'm trying to get data back from "ActiveAndroid" **I'm getting foreign key null**. I googled a lot but yet unable to trace issue. For more information please check below details--

Currently I have following model classes-- 
**1] Event.java class**

```
@Table(name = "Events")
public class Event extends Model
{

    @Column(name = "eventID")
    private int eventID;
    @Column(name = "eventName")
    private String eventName;   
    @Column(name = "Ground")
    private Ground ground;


    public Event() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Event(int eventID, String eventName,
            Ground ground) {
        super();
        this.eventID = eventID;
        this.eventName = eventName;     
        this.ground = ground;           
    }

    public int getEventID() {
        return eventID;
    }

    public void setEventID(int eventID) {
        this.eventID = eventID;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public Ground getGround() {
        return ground;
    }

    public void setGround(Ground ground) {
        this.ground = ground;
    }    
}
```

As shown in above "Event" model class, there is one foreign key i.e."Ground".

**2] Ground.java** class is--

```
Table(name = "Ground")
public class Ground extends Model
{
    @Column(name = "groundID")
    private int groundID;
    @Column(name = "groundName")
    private String groundName;

    public Ground() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getGroundID() {
        return groundID;
    }

    public void setGroundID(int groundID) {
        this.groundID = groundID;
    }

    public String getGroundName() {
        return groundName;
    }

    public void setGroundName(String groundName) {
        this.groundName = groundName;
    }

    public Ground(int groundID, String groundName)
 {
        super();
        this.groundID = groundID;
        this.groundName = groundName;
    }
}
```

**3] This is how I'm storing Events in "ActiveAndroid DB"**

```
ActiveAndroid.beginTransaction();
    try 
    {
           for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
           {
                list.get(i).save();

                /*
                   Also tried---
                   list.get(i).getGround.save();
                   list.get(i).save();
               */
           }
           ActiveAndroid.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } 
    finally 
    {
           ActiveAndroid.endTransaction();
    }
```

**4] This is how I'm getting Event list from "ActiveAndroid" DB**

```
public static List<Event> getAllEvents()
    {
        return new Select()
                .all()
                .from(Event.class)
                .execute();
    }
```

But after getting list from "ActiveAndroid", **I'm getting "Ground" field as null.** Please guide me where I'm getting wrong, also let me know if I can provide more information so that you can easily understand my problem. Thank you.!

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code it might help you.

```
 @Table(name = "Events")
public class Event extends Model {
    @Column(name = "eventID")
    private int eventID;
    @Column(name = "eventName")
    private String eventName;
    @Column(name = "Ground", onUpdate = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE, onDelete = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE)
    private Ground ground;


    public Event() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Event(int eventID, String eventName,
                 Ground ground) {
        super();
        this.eventID = eventID;
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.ground = ground;
    }

    public int getEventID() {
        return eventID;
    }

    public void setEventID(int eventID) {
        this.eventID = eventID;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public Ground getGround() {
        return getMany(Ground.class, "Ground");//or/*new Select().from(Ground.class).execute();*/
    }

    public void setGround(Ground ground) {
        this.ground = ground;
    }
}
```